# Slider / Line Marker on a Line Chart

Tags: c#, charts, winrt-xaml

I've created a Line Chart control. Now I'm trying to add a slider / line marker to the chart like in the picture (Bing Financial App). The goal is that I can move the slider and the red point sticks to the chartline and on the value changes according to the chartline.

[image]

How can I do this? How can I make sure that the red point sticks to the chartline?

Thanks

Comment: We won't know how to make the changes to your existing code base without seeing your original code. Please post [a minimal example of what needs to change](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and fully explain what needs to be modifed.

Comment: I'm just asking for a general way how to do it. I'm struggling with the points at all, that's why I can't post any code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would overlay a panel (like a `Canvas` or `Grid`) on top of your chart control, then put a thumb element of your design on top of it and perhaps make sure it has certain width by extending its area with an element of `Transparent` `Background` or `Fill` that will capture the inputs. Then you can handle `Manipulation` or `PointerMoved` events (make sure to call `Capture()` on the pointer in `PointerPressed` to not lose track of it if it leaves the bounds of the thumb while dragging) and change the position of the thumb when you drag. Based on the position of the thumb you would calculate the position of the red point which could be either part of the thumb or the chart itself.